# Error para tomar valores de un array de objetos y colocarlos en un componente

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

estoy aprendiendo js  y react.
Intento crear un quizgame, tomando los valores de un array de objetos, para que se visualicen en la aplicación. Sin embargo al hacerlo, me sale un error.
Me pueden explicar cual es la razón.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import preguntas from '../extras/preguntas.js'

export default function Pruebas() {

    const [preguntaActual, setPreguntaActual] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div className='pruebas-container'>
            <div>
                {preguntas[preguntaActual].pregunta}
            </div>
            <div>
                {preguntas[preguntaActual].opciones.map((respuesta) => (
                    <button> 
                        {respuesta.textoRespuesta}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>           
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: y cual es el error que sale? No entiendo para que usas preguntaActual como una variable de estado si nunca modificas su valor... segun entiendo siempre estas leyendo la primer pregunta

Comment: El código lo tomé de un tutorial. En el mismo, la aplicación funciona correctamente, en cambio en mi caso, el error que me sale es con respecto al preguntas.js  
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pregunta')

Comment: Puedes agregar el JSON que tiene la variable preguntas?

Comment: El archivo que contiene los base de datos de las preguntas es un array de objetos //preguntas.js  lo importe al inicio del componente